# 2D Draw Order in OpenTK

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, mono, opentk

So I have 4 Sprites, let's call them `Background`, `Overlay`, `Object A` and `Object B`.

1. `Background` sprite should be drawn first and act just like normal background.
2. `Overlay` sprite quite have complicated job,  `Overlay` is covered 50% area of `Background` but i want `Overlay` is transparent to `Background`, which mean i can see the `Background` even its covered by `Overlay` however, i want it not transparent to `Object A` and `Object B`, which mean if `Object A` and / or `Object B` is located / covered by `Overlay` those objects should not visible BUT the `Background` should visible fully.

any ideas to solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: and what if objA or B is `partialy`covered by overlay? I think you could adjust alpha blending between draw calls to fit your needs...

Comment: the covered part should not visible  
i think its not possible to use ordinary alpha blending, since the `Background` should visible even its covered by `Overlay`

Comment: If not possible with normal alpha blending (I've not dig very deeply this problem) but you could render to FBO your A,B and Overlay objects, with alpha blending disabled and then render resulting texture and background with alpha enabled...